# How to perform a SELECT in the results returned from a GROUP BY Druid?

Tags: sql, json, druid

I am having a hard time converting this simple SQL Query below into Druid:

```
SELECT country, city, Count(*) 
FROM people_data 
WHERE name="Mary" 
GROUP BY country, city;
```

So I came up with this query so far:

```
{
  "queryType": "groupBy",
  "dataSource" : "people_data",
  "granularity": "all",
  "metric" : "num_of_pages",
  "dimensions": ["country", "city"],
  "filter" : {
      "type" : "and",
      "fields" : [
          {
            "type": "in",
            "dimension": "name",
            "values": ["Mary"]
          },
          {
            "type" : "javascript",
            "dimension" : "email",
            "function" : "function(value) { return (value.length !== 0) }"
          }
      ]
  },
  "aggregations": [

    { "type": "longSum", "name": "num_of_pages", "fieldName": "count" }
  ],
  "intervals": [ "2016-07-20/2016-07-21" ]
}
```

The query above runs but it doesn't seem like groupBy in the Druid datasource is even being evaluated since I see people in my output with names other than Mary. Does anyone have any input on how to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer is that you cannot select arbitrary dimensions in your `groupBy` queries.

Strictly speaking even SQL query does not make sense. If for a given combination of `country, city` there are many different values of `name` and `street`, then how do you squeeze that into a single row? You have to aggregate them, e.g. by using `max` function.

In this case you can include the same column in your data as both dimension and metric, e.g. `name_dim` and `name_metric`,  and include corresponding aggregation over your metric, `max(name_metric)`.

Please note, that if these columns, `name` etc, have high granularity values, then that will kill Druid's roll-up feature.

Comment: I have updated the query above to make it more useful. After doing a `group by` on country and city, I grab the `country`, `city`, and `the count` of all of those rows in every group to see which country and city have the most amount of people named `Mary`. But do you happen to know how I can translate this query into Druid code (the `JSON` above)?

Comment: but your inner query seems to be exactly what you need. Group By with filter and `longSum` aggregations. Remove that outer query and try only the inner one.